# What are the criteria for posts to be included in "Top network posts" on new profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page, posts

From the name of it, certainly it looks for posts with the highest scores. However, recently I found that some of the posts are not listed.

Example: My [answer on UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76446/why-is-the-0-next-to-9-not-next-to-1/76471#76471) (not sure if it's that good, just because hot network question) was included in some point, but then it's not listed on [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241919/andrew-t?tab=profile). I guess it's because *the question was closed*, e.g as a dupe? (I don't have any hidden communities on the settings)

> [image: top network posts from per-site profile]

However, it's listed normally on [Stack Exchange profile for top posts](https://stackexchange.com/users/3359942/andrew-t?tab=top).

> [image: top posts on SE]

Also, what other criteria that makes the posts to be included/excluded in "Top network posts"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Source](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/)

For **Top posts** it says:

> **We’ll show off your best work.** Your top posts - along with the technologies or tags you’re strongest in - show others what you’re all about. And if you’re active on multiple communities, your *best stuff* from those sites will show in the sidebar, too.

I think, *best stuff* is referred to your top posts by adding filters of `closed:no duplicate:no`. And actually **best stuffs** is different from **top stuffs** as not described there.

But I think it could be better by phrasing it like **Best network posts**.

Comment: The link doesn't work. Could you please update it?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Updated ;).

Answer (score 10):

[shA.t's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254433/241919) has pretty much nailed it, and the summary from the blog itself is the key:

> And if you’re active on multiple communities, your<sup>1</sup> best stuff<sup>2</sup> from those sites<sup>3</sup> will show in the sidebar, too.

<sup>Numbering is added to clarify the point</sup>

The specific criteria are:

1. Not community wiki (`wiki:no`), they're 100% *your* posts ("Top posts" already excludes these posts)
2. Not in the closed questions (`closed:no duplicate:no`), they're the *best stuff* from your "Top posts"
3. Not from the site you're viewing the profile on (e.g SO posts won't be shown if the user is currently viewing the profile on SO; they're already listed on per-site "Top posts")
4. Has score of 5 or more (`score:5`), this is a prerequisite of "Top posts" on SE global profile.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to place this comment, but can you explain why [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1143670/marty) has no top network posts on any of his profiles? He has a number of posts that meet the criteria of not closed or duplicate, and he's active on a few sites, so shouldn't he have something in that box other than the annoying message left there by the new system? (I don't know him, so I apologize if using his profile is improper. It happened to jump out at me, then I found this question.)

Comment: After researching a bit, I just found out that the prerequisite for Top Posts also includes "must have score of 5 or more". You can check that by going to their SE profile and go to Top Posts. Thanks for making me notice this!

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for finding it and editing it into your answer!